# How to indicate to TypeScript that a property of an object extends object?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, type-narrowing

I am essentially trying to create a class that makes all properties of an object accessible through a get function on the object. These get operations should be chainable. An example of my desired behavior:

#### End Goal

```
const original = {
  property: {
    interiorProperty: 'value';
  }
};
const wrapped = new Wrapper(original);

console.log(wrapped.get('property'));
// {
//   interiorProperty: 'value';
// }

console.log(wrapped.get('property').get('interiorProperty'));
// 'value'
```

My reasoning for doing this is for better property access in an Angular template.

However, some properties of the object (or properties of properties) will eventually be primitives. I thought I was accounting for this - however, TypeScript disagrees.

#### Current Code

```
class Wrapper<OriginalType extends object> {
  private originalObject: OriginalType;

  constructor(obj: OriginalType) {
    this.originalObject = obj;
  }

  public get<Key extends keyof OriginalType>(key: Key) {
    const value = this.originalObject[key];
    if (typeof value === 'object') {
      // Error: Argument of type 'OriginalType[Key]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'object'.
      return new Wrapper(value);
    }
    return value;
  }
}
```

Full TypeScript error:

```
Argument of type 'OriginalType[Key]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'object'.
  Type 'OriginalType[keyof OriginalType]' is not assignable to type 'object'.
    Type 'OriginalType[string] | OriginalType[number] | OriginalType[symbol]' is not assignable to type 'object'.
      Type 'OriginalType[string]' is not assignable to type 'object'.ts(2345)
```

I don't understand why the `typeof` check doesn't tell TypeScript that `value` extends object inside of the if block. I thought perhaps it had to do with the type Key not being narrowed, but when I got fancy with the typing there (`key: OriginalType[Key] extends object ? Key : never`) it still had no effect.

I'm sure there's a way to accomplish this and the problem is simply my expertise, but for the life of me I can't figure it out.

Comment: You have two typos - `class Wrapper<OriginalType extends object> {` (should be Object and not object), and `const wrapped = new Wrapped(original);` (should be `Wrapper` and not `Wrapped`).

Comment: It should be noted that `number[]` extends `object`, too. `object` is a type you probably don't want to use. `Record<string, unknown>` is usually preferable to `object`.

Comment: Thanks @OriDrori - the first is what I needed, and the second was because I was typing the example freehand.

Comment: And great suggestion @AlexWayne - I'll make that change!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo on the `extend`, `object` should be `Object`

```
class Wrapper<OriginalType extends Object> {
  private originalObject: OriginalType;

  constructor(obj: OriginalType) {
    this.originalObject = obj;
  }

  public get<Key extends keyof OriginalType>(key: Key) {
    const value = this.originalObject[key];
    if (typeof value === 'object') {
      return new Wrapper(value); // ok
    }
    return value;
  }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDqBOYAOSCm8A8B5eBLA5rgHZggAqAnmtKgB4AuqRAJjFgEYBWqw9AfNADeAKGjQkeAG5hG0APZ5CJEB268AXNBwFipSmgDcw0dGByiEevACuvBQAo5XTdqV6qqAJRCTY+gAtcCAA6BR1lVR56aABeeS4jMQBfYzEka3YQXGBofFR6DABpVAoaBiZWaABrErkAMy1FXXIPPnsaik1iim8RMTEzC2jpEGtUWOgAoNCmiK4ogG0OgF1E-twG+3oPeugRsdiYuIByJzV6Y97ffvh863giaCJUAHc4RBR0e32vA2gAen+8iq1xS-Wgt3o90ePzWKSSQA)

Comment: Oh god. That's embarrassing. THANK YOU!!